# how to display this functions?

Tags: php, templates

I want to add this my page.php. Does anyone help me?

```
if(function_exists('add_theme_support')){
      add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'); 
      }


      function mallu_link_add_meta_box(){
      $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );
      foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
      add_meta_box('action_block', 'Action Block', 'mallu_link_meta_box_callback', $screen, 'normal'); 
      }
      }

      // Add meta boxes for action section on each post/page
      add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'mallu_link_add_meta_box');

      function mallu_link_meta_box_callback($post){
      // Security check
      wp_nonce_field('mallu_link_save_meta_box_data', 'mallu_link_meta_box_nonce');

      // Get values of the action block fields
      $action_prompt_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mallu_link_meta_prompt_text', true);
      $action_button_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mallu_link_meta_button_text', true);
      $action_button_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mallu_link_meta_button_link', true);


      // Display and populate fields from the database if it exists
      ?>
      <p>
      <label for="action_prompt_text">Action Prompt</label><br>
      <input class="widefat" type="text" name="action_prompt_text" id="action_prompt_text" placeholder="This should be short, to the point and less salesy." value="<?php echo esc_attr($action_prompt_text); ?>">
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="action_button_text">Action Button Text</label><br>
      <input class="widefat" type="text" name="action_button_text" id="action_button_text" placeholder="This should prompt the visitor to take an action." value="<?php echo esc_attr($action_button_text); ?>">
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="action_button_link">Action Button Link</label><br>
      <input class="widefat" type="url" name="action_button_link" id="action_button_link" placeholder="Copy and paste the link from the intended page." value="<?php echo esc_attr($action_button_link); ?>">
      </p>
      <?php
      }
      // Callback for saving metaboxes
      function mallu_link_save_meta_box_data($post_id) {


      // Security checks
      if(!isset($_POST['mallu_link_meta_box_nonce'])) return;
      if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mallu_link_meta_box_nonce'], 'mallu_link_save_meta_box_data')) return;
      if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

      if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
          return;
        }
      } else {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
          return;
        }
      }

      // Do the save/update
      if(isset($_POST['action_prompt_text'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'mallu_link_meta_prompt_text', sanitize_text_field($_POST['action_prompt_text']));
      }
      if(isset($_POST['action_button_text'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'mallu_link_meta_button_text', sanitize_text_field($_POST['action_button_text']));
      }
      if(isset($_POST['action_button_link'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'mallu_link_meta_button_link', esc_url($_POST['action_button_link']));
      }
      }

      // Save action block details when the post is saved/updated
      add_action('save_post', 'mallu_link_save_meta_box_data');
```

**I added this code in single.php but not showing**

```
<p><?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mallu_link_meta_prompt_text', true ) ); ?></p>
```

**But not displaying. please help**

Comment: functions and hooks shouldn't be in templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add function codes in functions.php. Then call in the single.php